# Somar horas de um array

Tags: php, informix

Preciso totalizar a coluna `hora_agente` do tipo `time`. E preciso que o valor retornado seja em horas. Podendo ser maior que 24horas.

No exemplo que fiz, está retornando 05:55, e deveria retornar 53:55. Acredito que quando dá 24horas, ele recomeça a contagem.

Se alguém souber fazer direto no SQL, melhor ainda, o banco é `informix`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
            $total_horas = 0;

            foreach ($dados_tempos as $t) {          

                $horariof = trim($t['HORA_AGENTE']);

                $partesf = explode(':', $horariof);
                $segundosf = $partesf[0] * 3600 + $partesf[1] * 60;

                $total_horas += $segundosf;
            }        

            $horas_geral = gmdate("h:i:s", $total_horas);

            echo $horas_geral;

            //resultado = 05:55:00
            //resultado esperado = 53:55
```

Answer (score 1):

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/ltuiR4)

```
$times = array('24:10','8:25','6:45','7:05','7:00','0:30');

$seconds = 0;

foreach ( $times as $time )
{
list( $g, $i ) = explode( ':', $time );
$seconds += $g * 3600;
$seconds += $i * 60;
}

$hours = floor( $seconds / 3600 );
$seconds -= $hours * 3600;
$minutes = floor( $seconds / 60 );

echo "{$hours}:{$minutes}";
```

[list](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php) - é um elemento nativo da linguagem PHP e permite realizar atribuições de valores de um array para um conjunto de variáveis de forma simplificada.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função para fazer esse tratamento, e apenas chamar ela no final do seu laço.

```
function convertTime( $total_hours ) 
{
    $hours   = floor( $total_hours / 3600 );
    $minutes = floor( ( $total_hours - ( $hours * 3600 ) ) / 60 );
    $seconds = floor( $total_hours % 60 );

    return $hours . ":" . $minutes . ":" . $seconds;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
echo convertTime( 194100 ); // 53:55:00
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está justamente na função [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php), pois ela formatará uma data a partir de um timestamp ([Unix Epoch](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix)). Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
gmdate("d/m/Y h:i:s", '1000000'); // 12/01/1970 01:46:40
```

Você poderia somar/dividir/multiplicar o tempo que você já calculou, para chegar ao tempo final. Entretanto, eu não gosto muito dessa aboradgem, pois, deixa de lado o que o PHP possui internamente já implementado.

Neste caso, o PHP possui uma classe específica para trabalhar com intervalos de tempo/data, que é a classe [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). Entretanto, não é tão trivial assim trabalhar ela para o seu caso em específico, pois, nativamente, você não pode somar um DateInterval a outro.

Outro detalhe é o formato que o DateInterval necessita para ser criado, que é diferente do formato de data tradicional (digamos assim).

Por outro lado, pode-se utilizar a classe DateTime em conjunto, o que nos ajuda a criar um DateInterval sem alterar o formato vindo do banco de dados.

```
//é necessária uma data base (00:00:00) - $baseDate
//e uma data para adicionar/somar os tempos vindos do SGBD - $date
$baseDate = clone $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s' , '00:00:00');

//dados vindo do banco de dados
$array = [
    '04:30',
    '05:30',
    '04:23',
    '02:35',
    '01:50',
    '03:25',
    '03:40',
    '02:30'
];    

//percorre cada valor do array
foreach($array as $time)
{
    //cria-se o date time com o tempo informado
    $dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i' , $time);

    //realiza o diff com a $baseDate para criar o DateInterval
    $diff = $baseDate->diff($dateTime);

    //adiciona o diff ao DateTime que somará o tempo
    $date->add($diff);
}

//realiza o último diff entre o DateTime de soma e a base date
$interval = $baseDate->diff($date);

//DateInterval mantêm em dias (%a) tudo que for acima de 24 horas.
$hours = $interval->format('%H') + ($interval->format('%a') * 24);

//exibe o tempo
echo $hours.$interval->format(':%I'); // Saída: 28:23
```

O código ficou um pouco extenso pela explicação, entretanto, acaba-se utilizando objetos que podem ser reutilizados para exibição e outros cálculos quando for necessário.